# react-vega- Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vega

> /node_modules/vega-embed/build/src/embed.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'vega-lite' in 'E:\polymerui\polymerui\node_modules\vega-embed\build\src'

In my dependencies
"react-vega": "^7.1.1",
"vega": "^5.9.1",
"vega-lite": "^4.0.2",

So I am currently working in react (obviously). I wanted to Add vega to my application.

To start with I ran

```
npm install vega vega-lite react-vega --save
```

I did no other npm installs.

Imported vega into one of my components.

```
import { Vega } from 'react-vega';
```

Added a component using one of the examples.

```
<Vega spec={this.state.spec} data={this.data} signalListeners={this.statesignalListeners} />
```

Using also things from the examples

```
spec: {
      "width": 400,
      "height": 200,
      "data": [{ "name": "table" }],
      "signals": [
        {
          "name": "tooltip",
          "value": {},
          "on": [
            { "events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum" },
            { "events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "{}" }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    signalListeners: { hover: this.handleHover }

handleHover = (args) => {
console.log(args);
}
```

I refresh the page and the error comes up.

I cannot argue with the error, that file does not exist there, I am just confused why its looking for it there then.

Or if I use

```
{ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('bar-container') ) }
```

I get the following error:

> ./node_modules/vega-encode/node_modules/vega-util/index.js
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\polymerui\polymerui\node_modules\vega-encode\node_modules\vega-util\index.js'

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? Are you in the right folder when installing `react-vega`? And have you tried `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i`?

Comment: Yes I am in the right folder when installing react-vega, it is there.

Comment: I will try a reinstall

Comment: Did not fix it. Same problem.